# Can a robots.txt disallow use an asterisk for product id wildcard?

Tags: seo, bigcommerce, robots.txt

Is the following valid in my robots.txt file?

```
Disallow: /*?action=addwishlist&product_id=*
```

rather than writing individually for every product like below:

```
Disallow: /*?action=addwishlist&product_id=1212
```

Or do I need to define below line for each individual products?

```
Disallow: /*?action=addwishlist&product_id=1212
Disallow: /*?action=addwishlist&product_id=1213
Disallow: /*?action=addwishlist&product_id=1214
```

or `*` sign will be taken as any product id. `product_id=*`

Comment: What spiders do you care about?  Do you care about just the search engine spiders (Googlebot, Bingbot, etc) or do you care about all the other less sophisticated spiders?

Comment: no just googlebot, bingbot etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googlebot recognizes the asterisk in place of the product ID as tested with their [robots.txt test tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en):

[image]

You could also leave the asterisk off, because `robots.txt` rules are all "starts with" rules. An asterisk at the end of the rule is equivalent to the same rule without the asterisk.

[image]

Keep in mind that while the major search engines support wildcards in `Disallow` rules, other bots won't. Wildcards in disallow were not part of the original robots.txt specification from [robotstxt.org](https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).  Less sophisticated crawlers that don't understand these wildcards will still crawl these URLs.

Comment: Thanks I keep asterisk sign for now as its not generating the error in google test. :) thanks for your help really appreciate.